# The php-mapscript does not work on Opensuse 13.1

Tags: php, opensuse, mapserver

I installed php-extension **php-mapscript-6.4.1** and restarted apache.

The installation looks like successfully. The appropriate files is established as for other working extensions:

1. In */etc/php5/conf.d/* directory:

**mapscript.ini**

with *extension=php_mapscript.so* string.

2. In */usr/lib/php5/extensions/* directory:

**php_mapscript.so** - link to php_mapscript.so.1

**php_mapscript.so.1** - link to php_mapscript.so.6.4.1

**php_mapscript.so.6.4.1** - shared library

But the extension does not work,
**php -m** or **phpinfo()** does not show a presence of the php_mapscript and **extension_loaded('php_mapscript')** returns FALSE.

Thanx for any help.

Comment: Did you install MapServer itself? php-mapscript won't work without it. And is there a particular reason you're using version 6.4 instead of 7.0? See http://mapserver.org.

Comment: The OpenSuse repository doesn't contain  v 7.0, v 6.4.1 only.
I prefer to get software from the native repository rather than
compiling from source every time. So the MapServer was installed with Mapscript as its dependency automaticly.

Answer (score 0):

I think your mapscript.ini might be incorrect. Mine has the full path to the extension:

```
; Enable php_mapscript
extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_mapscript.so
```

I'm on a different distribution of Linux, so your path would be different than mine, of course.

Comment: Unfortunately the defining of full path does not help.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. But this smells to me like a PHP/Linux issue more than a MapServer/MapScript one. You'll be able to get more MapServer eyes on this by asking on the mailing list, mapserver-users@lists.osgeo.org. See http://www.mapserver.org/community/lists.html